# Как установить указанную версию laravel

Tags: laravel, composer

У меня composer по умолчанию устанавливает laravel версии 5.4, но документации по-русски еще маловато, да и не привычно
Как настроить composer на установку именно laravel версии 5.3??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.3.*
```